# How to know Ubuntu Source Code version?

Tags: source-code

I downloaded the source code using the following command:

```
git clone git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-precise.git
```

This gives me a folder named : ubuntu-precise.

But what is its version? How do I know this?

By the way my running kernel is:

```
#lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

Also:

3.8.0-38-generic #56~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 13 16:23:47 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

**changelog is located at many places**

```
./arch/arm/lib/changebit.S
./debian.master/changelog.historical
./debian.master/changelog
./drivers/staging/rtl8192u/changes
./ubuntu/omnibook/debian/changelog
```

So 
I checked in debian.master/changelog
These are the first few lines:

```
linux (3.2.0-61.92) precise; urgency=low

  [ Kamal Mostafa ]

  * Release Tracking Bug
    - LP: #1300455

  [ Upstream Kernel Changes ]
```

Comment: Try looking into Changelog

Comment: changelog is at many places, I update my question

Comment: Probably the 3rd.

Comment: the top line shows:  linux (3.2.0-61.92) precise, is this the version of the source code?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

It's in the first four lines of the top level [Makefile](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git?p=ubuntu/ubuntu-precise.git;a=blob;f=Makefile;h=207f3d7d23cec96402963fc9518e8e0df82e0d03;hb=HEAD):

```
1 VERSION = 3
2 PATCHLEVEL = 2
3 SUBLEVEL = 55
4 EXTRAVERSION =
```

Answer (score 0):

As Sylvain says, the Vanilla version is in the Makefile. But if you want to know *package version*, it is better to look into changelog. It's the common Ubuntu practice.

For example, `pidgin/ChangeLog`:

```
Pidgin and Finch: The Pimpin' Penguin IM Clients That're Good for the Soul

version 2.10.9 (2/2/2014):
    XMPP:
    * Fix problems logging into some servers including jabber.org and
      chat.facebook.com. (#15879)
```

From the file we can know that it's version is 2.10.9

And in your case, the `linux (3.2.0-61.92) precise` is the version of sources.